# Regular Expression for a string look like DF-1234567 or N/A

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

Could you please help me out for this scenario.

Regular Expression for a string look like `DF-1234567` or `N/A` in ASP.Net.

String contain `DF-` and 7 or more digits or `N/A`.

e.g.:

```
DF-1234567
DF-12345678
N/A
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have to tried something? show here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Use **RegularExpressionValidator** in Visual Studio and in **ValidationExpression** property:

```
(DF-(\d){7,})|NA
```

Comment: It should be (DF-(\d){7,})|N\/A, because it's N/A and not NA.

Comment: @Regu -- you have to escape a forward slash?